# How to create an object from radio input groups?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, object

I'm really struggling to get my head around how to create the structure I want. I need the object to look like this and be built based on the html in my codepen:

```
obj = {
    a1 : {
        q1 : 0,
        q2 : 0
    },
    a2 : {
        q1 : 0,
        q2 : 0
    }
}
```

(a1 is answer 1, a2 is answer 2 etc.)

(q1 is question 1, q2 is question 2 etc.)

http://codepen.io/matt3224/pen/aNvmYX?editors=1010

To explain, I have a quiz. Each question has 4 answers of which the user selects 1. I need to work out the majority and display the appropriate result.

For example if theres 5 questions and the user clicks the 1st answer for every question then it shows the first result (q1a1, q2a1, q3a1, q4a1, q5a1 = result 1) if the user answers (q1a2, q2a2, q3a2, q4a3, q5a4 = result 2) so its a majority result.

The object has 2 levels, the list of answers 1-4 and the choice of that answer for every question. I need it that way so I can count the sets of answers and know the majority.

I hope this all makes sense. I'm not sure where to really begin to be honest. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure, you want the first group to be the answer and not the question in your object? Do you mind to use the jQuery library?

Comment: What is the higher level problem you are trying to solve? it's not clear what the use case is for this object

Comment: jQuery is fine as long as its not really poor performance. Here's what i have managed to do which uses the question as the high level however it seems more complex and more difficult to calculate the majority. You can see im creating the data object but really it would be simpler and easier to calculate the majority if it was answers then questions. http://codepen.io/matt3224/pen/RaWRoY?editors=1011